# No funciona redireccion con Ingress en minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Estoy estudiando como crear pods en el entorno minikube.

El pod es un contenedor con pgadmin4 que es basicamente una app web que atiende en el puerto 80.

El despliegue lo cree con el siguiente archivo

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: pgadmin4
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: pgadmin4  
  type: NodePort 
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: pgadmin4
  labels:
     app: pgadmin4
spec:
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: pgadmin4
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: dpage/pgadmin4:4.11
        name: pgadmin4
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
          value: mimail@gmail.com
        - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
          value: mipassword      
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: pgadmin4
```

Creo que esta bien esta parte, ya que no veo errores en el dashboard.

[image: descripcion del despliegue]

[image: servicio en el dashboard]

ademas con la instruccion

```
kubectl service pgadmin4
```

Puedo ver la consola en el browser sin problemas

[image: acceso a la aplicacion]

Y la IP que me da minikube se ve consistente con la URL que entrega services.

```
PS C:\kubernetes> minikube ip
192.168.137.213
PS C:\kubernetes> minikube service pgadmin4 --url
http://192.168.137.213:31122
```

Entonces ahora quiero exponer la pagina al mundo, por lo que lei una de las maneras es con Ingress, por lo que cree un archivo para crear el objeto Ingress, habilite el complemento y aplique un archivo que lei era obligatorio para usar ingress.

```
minikube addons enable ingress

kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/master/deploy/static/mandatory.yaml
```

y el archivo que crea el objeto ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: pgsql-ingress
  annotations:
    pgsql.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /pgadmin4
        backend:
          serviceName: pgadmin4
          servicePort: 80
```

Lo aplique y no dio error

```
PS C:\kubernetes> kubectl get ing
NAME            HOSTS   ADDRESS           PORTS   AGE
pgsql-ingress   *       192.168.137.213   80      77m
```

Y si ejecuto un describe del objeto ingress

```
PS C:\kubernetes> kubectl describe ingress pgsql-ingress
Name:             pgsql-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          192.168.137.213
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (172.17.0.6:8080)
Rules:
  Host  Path  Backends
  ----  ----  --------
  *
        /pgadmin4   pgadmin4:80 (172.17.0.5:80)
Annotations:
  pgsql.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target:  /
Events:                                        <none>
```

Y si describo el pod

```
PS C:\kubernetes> kubectl describe deployment pgadmin4
Name:               pgadmin4
Namespace:          default
CreationTimestamp:  Mon, 05 Aug 2019 15:14:56 -0400
Labels:             app=pgadmin4
Annotations:        deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:           app=pgadmin4
Replicas:           1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:       Recreate
MinReadySeconds:    0
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=pgadmin4
  Containers:
   pgadmin4:
    Image:      dpage/pgadmin4:4.11
    Port:       80/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL:     mimail@gmail.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD:  mipassword
    Mounts:                      <none>
  Volumes:                       <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   pgadmin4-6fddf8dd47 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

Y si describo el servicio

```
PS C:\kubernetes> kubectl describe service pgadmin4
Name:                     pgadmin4
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=pgadmin4
Type:                     NodePort
IP:                       10.103.197.226
Port:                     <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  31122/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.5:80
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Pero voy al browser con la url del endpoint de ingress mas la path, me dice que no se encuentra.

[image: No funciona redireccion]

El ambiente en que trabajo es un Windows 10 con Hyper-V con conexion a internet por Wireless, por lo que para crear la maquina virtual tuve que crear un conmutador virtual interno (dentro de Hyper-V) y en la conexion de la tarjeta compartile internet a ese conmutador que cree dentro de Hyper-V.

Answer (score 1):

Encontre el problema y era la seccion annotations

```
annotations:
    pgsql.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Yo suponia que la seccion annotations era solo un comentario, pero resulta que en esta seccion se colocan comandos, estos estan descritos en:

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations

La anotacion

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Me reescribe la path de la peticion a "/" en el server interno. Pero eso tampoco me sirvio, ya que el propio sitio web genera redirecciones, por ejemplo si yo envio /pgadmin4 ingress invocara con /, la pagina llega al browser y cambia la url por /login, esa url se va a ingress pero ingress no conoce /login y da error. Por lo tanto cree en el archivo host de mi equipo una alias para la ip donde esta sirviendo ingress

```
192.168.137.213 pgadmin4
```

Y luego cambie el objeto ingress para decirle que redireccione por host y olvide la path

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: pgsql-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: pgadmin4
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: pgadmin4
          servicePort: 80
```

Lo malo de este esquema es que los equipos clientes deberan modificar su archivo hosts, pero no se me ocurre otra manera ya que la redireccion es una accion que ocurre entre el sitio web y el browser. Pero al menos funciona.